# Observations weight-age in a Machine Learning model

Tags: machine-learning, weighted-data

I want to know is there any way in R/Python to specify to the model to emphasize its learning more on specific subset of data , while it considers the whole data.

For example - i have sales behavior data from 2011 to 2016 and i am predicting likelihood to buy in 2017 - i want the model to emphasize more on 2015-2016 data ( i.e. capture new learning - which may not be very evident when you consider the whole data from 2011 ). I can always build a separate model for for that time period or consider a time year variable for it to capture the effect , but is there some way to specify to the model that focus more on rows ( x to y ) as in give more weight-age to the learning from this subset from whole data.

Comment: many many learners allow weights to be associated with the samples.  h2o.ai is one of them. The answer is "yes.  easily.  most of them".  From the basic lm to the advanced keras/pytorch there are weights.  CART, Ensembles, and SVM.  Oversampling works like weights, but costs more compute and memory.  It is a bit of an inelegant hack when there is an input called "weights" that was built to do the job correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One general approach is to try oversampling more/undersampling less important data.

With respect to weights it will depend on the algorihtm.

In **Python** it seems many algorithms in **scikit-learn** have it, for example [SVMs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html), [Stochastic Gradient Descent classifiers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_weighted_samples.html), and [Random Forests](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) have it, though unfortunately I can't find general documentation on this parameter.

Comment: Since it is time bound data, I have all the data for 2016 and previous years in my train. Hence over sampling won't really help. What I want to do is provide learners be it weak or strong from 2016 to be given more room and lower acceptance threshold, since they are new trends. I'll search for the arguments in scikit learn functions in python, but it'll be great if you can provide an example and which argument in function it is?

Comment: Dod you try over/undersampling? Why do you think it won't work?

Comment: Did you see examples? They all use sample_weight argument

Comment: Yes , i saw but how to i emphasize which sample to overweight - or yes , i can manually create those samples . But i can't directly assign a weight specifying say rows x to y ( so that whatever sample a say random forest takes while building trees from this subset of x to y , it assigns more weight )

Comment: I don't really understand. What you are trying to accomplish.

From the original point I understood that you want for 2016 examples to be more important. You can achieve it by adding bigger weights to 2016 examples and smaller weights to other examples. The algorithms I've shown can incorporate these weights.

Comment: @JakubBartczuk as I see it has only class_weight parameter, which does not allow you to specify this and this samples should be weighted more.

Comment: @Alina, `sample_weight` is available in the `fit` method when it's available, not an init parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Keras offers the ability to apply weight to every sample invdividually.
You can view the entire keras model api [here](https://keras.io/models/sequential/).
The description of the sample_weight parameter of keras "fit" function is as follows:

> sample_weight: Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). You can either pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape  (samples, sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile().

As far as i know keras is used for neural networks, so this feature is available for those but not for other models like svm or random forest